# How to convert string to date time value in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am new to Snowflake and need help in converting string to date time.

I am loading the .csv file into Snowflake stage table which is all having string columns.
One of the column name `END_TIME_STAMP` (STRING) having values like below

| END_TIME_STAMP |
| --- |
| 08-09-2022 06:23:10 AM |
| 08-09-2022 11:10:10 PM |

My requirement is how to convert this values to 24 hr time format in snowflake.

OutPut:

| END_TIME_STAMP |
| --- |
| 08-09-2022 06:23:10.000 |
| 08-09-2022 23:10:10.000 |

i tried using `TO_TIMESTAMP()`, `TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ()`, but it throughs me below error
`Timestamp '6:23:20 AM' is not recognized`

Answer (score 0):

Using `TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP` with [time format](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/date-time-input-output.html#time-formats):

> The AM format specifier allows values with either AM or PM.

```
ALTER SESSION SET TIMESTAMP_NTZ_OUTPUT_FORMAT = 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF3';

SELECT TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP('08-09-2022 06:23:10 AM','DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')
      ,TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP('08-09-2022 06:23:10 PM','DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS AM');
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This is not helped me